# conda package selector on target environment

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I wonder if you can specify a selector on a dependency within a conda package recipe to only select it, if a given package is installed within the installation environment target.

So image a recipe like this:

```yaml
package:
  name: foo
  version: 1.0

requirements:
  run:
    - python
    - my_dep_which_requires_something  # [ installed(jupyterlab>=3) ]
```

As you see the last line contains a requirement, which should be optional upon an already installed package named "jupyterlab". Eventually this is already implemented, but I'm unaware of it/ was unable to find it - or it has to be designed/written first.

Glad for any answer pointing me towards the right direction.